# How to trigger a click event on child element got using querySelector on native element in angular2/angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I tried the code below but didn't work. I'm using Angular4. I want to trigger a click event if the input of handle click is not less than 3.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'box-frame',
    template: `
            <div>
              <div (click)="handleClick(i)" id="box{{i}}" *ngFor="let i of array"></div>   
            </div>
          `
})
export class BoxFrameComponent implements OnInit {
    array: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) { };
    ngOnInIt() {
    };
    handleClick(n: number) {
        if (n < 3) {
            console.log(n);
        } else {
            let smallBox = this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#box' + n - 1);
            //this didn't work
            smallBox.dispatchEvent('click');
        }

    };
};
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Wanna trigger click event manually on a div with specific id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
smallBox.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));
```

Comment: I tried it in the browser console and it worked. I don't see why it wouldn't work in Angular. Perhaps you're doing something wrong with the listening. Are you trying to create an endless loop? What does "didn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: Glad to hear. . .